# spring mvc get mapping controller method from interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Now I have a controller like this

```
@RequestMapping("/content/delete.json")
@Security(auth = AuthType.REQUIRED)
public ModelAndView deleteIndex(User user, @RequestParam("id") long id) {

}
```

Now I am trying to get controller mapping method from interceptor and getting the annotation of the method.

```
Method method = RestRequestURLUtil.getInvokedMethod(handler, request);
Security security = method.getAnnotation(Security.class);
if(security.getAuth() == AuthType.REQUIRED) {
    do some validate here
}
```

Are there any classes like RestRequestURLUtil in spring?

thanks in advance :)

edit:

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml,
                /WEB-INF/interceptor-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

interceptor-server.xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
    <bean class="com.test.web.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor" init-method="init">
     ...
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptor>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question? If you are wondering how to check if handler method was annotated with `@Security` in the interceptor you can do so like this `if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) { HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler; if (method.getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(Security.class)) {...}`

Comment: I think the handler is an instance of controller class.Let me debug and check it out. @KresimirNesek

Comment: Class test = handler.getClass(); debug result is search.controllers.SearchJobController @KresimirNesek

Comment: Interesting... Could you post the code / configuration where you register the interceptor?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are you testing the correct URL? It seems impossible to have a controller as a `handler` argument using `@RequestMapping`. It sounds to me like a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` figured out the handler.

Comment: The URL is correct :) @Bart

Comment: Hmmm. Is `SearchJobController` the controller you're expecting? Looking at your handler method it doesn't seem logical. Maybe another mapping is taking precendence?

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? It should be 3.1 or newer. Are you sure that deleteIndex(...) is executed when you visit the URL (and not something else)? Otherwise, I'm unfortunately out of ideas :(

Comment: SearchJobController is just an example here :) I am sure the controller method is called @Bart

Comment: the version of spring is 3.0.5.RELEASE.Is it the problem?@KresimirNesek

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The annotation on the controller's method can be inspected in the interceptor by means of the HandlerMethod object that the framework should pass as handler Object.

```
if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
    HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
    if (method.getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(Security.class)) {
       //do processing
    }
}
```

However, according to the spring documentation in [HandlerMethod javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html?is-external=true), HandlerMethod class was introduced in Spring 3.1. It seems that, in versions prior to 3.1, handler object was a Controller instance, which makes fetching the annotation of the invoked controller method difficult.

You can either upgrade to 3.1. and fetch the annotation from HandlerMethod object or attempt to parse all the RequestMapping annotations on the controller methods and then attempt to determine which method was invoked by comparing RequestMappings with request URI.

If upgrade is not an option, another alternative would be to use AOP instead of mvc interceptor.